# Remove single quote before and after the comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to remove the brackets, single quote before and after the comma from a variable in a elegant way in SQL

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @str = N'(''202102'',''202104'',''202105'',''202106'',''202107'')'
```

Expected output

```
'202102,202104,202105,202106,202107'
```

I have tried and managed to remove the brackets but couldn't progress further for the single quotes.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, 2, LEN(@str) - 2); -- '202102','202104','202105','202106','202107'
```

Also tried the following which removes the whole lot after the first value.

```
SELECT LEFT(@str, CHARINDEX(',', @str) - 1)  -- '202102'
```

Comment: Your definition of the string isn't clear.  Where does it begin and end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this char(39) based approach

```
replace(replace(replace(@str, char(39), ''),'(',char(39)),')',char(39))
```

Comment: Thanks. Shall I get your assistance for a different question if you don't mind please?

Comment: @Sri I am about to call it a day, but if you could post a new question, chances are you'll get the assistance you need

Comment: Thanks Phil, It's a combination of mixed questions and I just need bit of guidance. But it's okay will manage that. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 4):

I think this does what you want:

```
select replace(replace(replace(str, ''',''', ','), '(''', ''), ''')', '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=347504632934198b94ef3b80d0a71e24) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi,  I have updated my question. It doesn't return as a string now. Can you please have a look at the db<>fiddle please?

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d647360e1ec5dc76e73ac419efd3a356